# Getting classname of a object in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an object reference and it could be a reference to an object of type 'FooInvalidResults'

There is a file called FooInvalidResults.pm and there is a line 'package FooInvalidResults' in it.

will the following work?

```
my $class = blessed $result;
if ($class eq 'FooInvalidResults') {
  # do something
} else {
  # do something else
}
```

Answer (score 17):

String-comparing class names is generally a bad idea, because it breaks polymorphism based on subtypes, and because it's generally not good OO practice to be that nosy about intimate details of an object like its exact package name.

Instead, write `$result->isa('FooInvalidResults')` — or, if you're paranoid about the possibility that `$result` isn't an object at all, `blessed $result && $result->isa('FooInvalidResults')`.

Using `UNIVERSAL::isa` is a bad idea because some objects (for instance, mock objects for testing) have legitimate reasons to override the `isa` method, and calling `UNIVERSAL::isa` breaks that.

Comment: In your opinion, is `UNIVERSAL::isa` always a bad idea, or can it be a viable solution for simple cases?

Comment: @MarcoDeLellis if there are cases where it makes sense to use, it's definitely not *simple* ones. It might make sense when writing a custom mro or something, but it should never be used for ordinary purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you use `UNIVERSAL::isa`?

```
if UNIVERSAL::isa( $result, "FooInvalidResults" ) {
   ...
}
```

This was **bad advice**, please use

```
$obj->isa( 'FooInvalidResults' );
```

I wasn't full aware of the difference between subroutine call ( BAD ) and method call ( GOOD ), but it became clear after I did some RTFM myself ( `perldoc UNIVERSAL` ).
Thanks ( and +1 ) to all folks that pointed out my fault.

Comment: Please don't advise anyone to use UNIVERSAL::ISA! If someone knows, when it's dangerous to use, he wouldn't ask...

Comment: @JanHartung Roger that. I wasn't aware that `UNIVERSAL::isa` was such a timebomb. Maybe I haven't abused `isa` enough to get into trouble.

Comment: $obj->isa doesn't work when I want to guarantee an object is a member of the superclass and not a member of some subclass.

Comment: @PhilGoetz it's not generally a good idea to do such a thing. The Liskov substitution principle says that any subclass should be substitutable for a parent class object.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do the job with the `ref()` builtin rather than `Scalar::Util::blessed()`:

```
$ perl -E '$ref = {}; bless $ref => "Foo"; say ref $ref'
Foo
```

Note that if the reference is not blessed, this will return the type of reference:

```
$ perl -E '$ref = {}; say ref $ref'
HASH
```

However, as others have mentioned, `UNIVERSAL::isa` is a better solution.

Comment: Please don't advise anyone to use UNIVERSAL::ISA! If someone knows, when it's dangerous to use, he wouldn't ask...